# Eclipse, refactoring a java method into a another class

Tags: eclipse

How can I refactor(move) a Java method in classA into classB and have all references to the method to it updated?

Is this supported in Eclipse ?

Comment: Well I don't think so , at least in my case references were not updated :(

Comment: I'm not sure I see how updating the references could be done. Your method would be called by instances of classA somewhere in the code. Updating the references in this case would imply that all instances of classA become instances of classB which may have many other side effects.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For a static method, you can right click and select 'Move'.

```
Obj1.myMethod()
```

would then get 'moved' to

```
Obj2.myMethod()
```

and eclipse would fix your imports etc.

For a non-static method, this may not work depending on the relationship between classA and classB.

```
Obj1 myobj1 = new Obj1();
myobj1.myMethod();
myobj1.myOtherMethod();
```

If you move myMethod() to a different class, the refactoring would have to change the object initialization.  If myOtherMethod isn't getting moved, then it can't just change the type of myobj1 to Obj2 because then myOtherMethod won't work.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I get it now. To move a non-static method, you have to include it has to exist in the parameters of the method I believe. "The target must therefore be the declaring class of a parameter or field type"  ...  Not sure what "or field type" means. Do you know? Here is also a good link: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html

Comment: A field is a member variable to a class.  In `Person.name`, Person is the class, name is the field.

Answer (score 11):

- Select the method in Outline view
- Refactor > Move

If you want to move the method to a new class
- Refactor > Extract Class

Comment: `Extract Class` insists on extracting some member variables to the new class.  This is annoying if you want to move the method because it doesn't depend on any instance state.

Comment: The `Move` and `Extract Class` wizards are clunky - I'm using `Luna 4.4.2`. The way I got it to work was: Manually created the new class and then I used the wizard to move the methods. It only moves one at a time, but it's ok because it refactors all calls to those methods.

Comment: Extract class: "The selected type does not contain any usable fields"