# How to transfer a function to another java file

Tags: java, android, class

I am practicing my Android skills and wrote a little programm which has do validate an input.
Ive got 10 input files and 5 different validators and now my MainAcitvity.java file is a little bit overloaded. 
Now I want to transfer the validators to have the possibility to use them system wide.

But I have no idea how to transfer it.
This is a one part of my MainAcitvity:

```
[...]
TextWatcher loginchecker = new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence login, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence login, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable login) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{3,}");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(login);

            if (login.hashCode() == loginname.getText().hashCode()){
                loginnameValid = m.find();
            }
            checkButton2();
        }
    };

    loginname.addTextChangedListener(loginchecker);

public void checkButton2(){
    if (loginnameValid && passwortvalid && mailValid && mobilValid){
        weiterFertig2.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        weiterFertig2.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
[...]
```

How do I transfer the validate method? Is it the right way to apply a new Java Class in my Package folder with all the needede variables?

Sorry for those dumb questions.

Rastaman

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you looking for tool support? maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331352/eclipse-refactoring-a-java-method-into-a-another-class

Comment: Sorry. system wide is not the right right expression. I want to use the validator in multiple Activities. But I dont want to copy the whole code for every Activity.

Comment: You need to extract / encapsulate those anonymous classes into named classes. E.g. `public class LoginChecker implements TextWatcher {...}`.

Comment: "Cut and paste" would be the method to transfer them to another file.

Comment: You could make the method `static`. So, you can call it from all the other Activities.