# How to move static method in eclipse to different class

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I've got a public static method in class A: `A.myMethod()`. Now I want to move it to class B. I don't do that by cut and paste because then all calls won't work anymore. So I want to make use of eclipse's refactoring engine. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331532) I go to my method and open the refacotring move dialogue there. It askes me to enter a destiantion type for my method. I'm not sure what to enter there. Can you help me?

Comment: Um, you enter the name of class B, given that that's what you want the destination type to be...

Comment: Firstly, Create a method in Class B. And then refactor A.myMethod() to B.myMethod(). Finally remove your method in Class A

Comment: @janani That's wrong. Eclipse does everything for you. The method should only be in class A. Eclipse will move it and set references correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Destination Type for method is the class to where you want to move the method.

For you destination type would be Class B.
This dialog also has a browse button, in which you can search for B and select it.

If you are not sure what happens, create a test method in Class A and then use the above method to move it to Class B.

Comment: I just entered `B`there first, but what you have to do is to enter `package.B`.

Comment: click Browse and search for the class B, you can select the class you are looking for